# AJW Feed Parser + character/word limit

Tags: feedparser, magpie

I have the plugin working fine and pulling in {description} however I'd like to be able to shorten the length of that text. I've tried the following addons:

Character Limit, Word Limit, and TruncHtml

I also tried to set this up using Magpie RSS Parser, and none of these worked with that either.  Is this just not possible?

Thanks

Edited to add: Also tried Hacksaw

Edited to add code:

`{exp:magpie url="{embed:feed}" limit="3" refresh="720"}
    {items}
        {title}
        {exp:eehive_hacksaw char="100"}
            {description}
        {/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
    {/items}
{/exp:magpie}`

I have a feeling this is a parsing issue.

Comment: Can you post some template code examples that didn't work for you?

Comment: Added the code. I switched to magpie but also same issue with FeedParser. I think it's a parse order issue.

Comment: Thanks! I have a bunch of custom plugins in the wild, I'll see if I can defeat this issue. This IS a custom plugin issue, and not a different type of addon? I can try and debug whatever, but clarification helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will definitely work, and you're right it's a parse order issue. You just need the `parse="inward"` parameter on the magpie tag.

```
{exp:magpie url="{embed:feed}" limit="3" refresh="720" parse="inward"}
    {items}
        {title}
        {exp:eehive_hacksaw char="100"}
            {description}
        {/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
    {/items}
{/exp:magpie}
```

From the ExpressionEngine docs on [changing parsing order when using plugins:](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/plugins.html#changing-parsing-order)

> You may change the parsing order and instruct ExpressionEngine to
>   parse an outer Plugin first. This is done by adding a parse=”inward”
>   parameter to the Plugin opening tag. Using that parameter will tell EE
>   to parse that Plugin before parsing any Plugins inside of it.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I remembered that parameter about 2 days later. I always forget. Thanks for adding that info here. I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Trunch and Hacksaw should work, but, understand that they'd be truncating the content on the front-end / template side, and wouldn't be altering the actual content in the database.

I believe you could set the description field to a text input and set the maximum length, and all of the fields would get truncated on the database-side. It wouldn't look very good (things would get cut-off mid-word), but, that's how you could do it on the back-end with the actual data.